# Looking for specific value with if statement

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I have a large dataset in excel (and it will keep growing) of products' orders.

The dataset look like this

```
Product   Date         Lsat24               Next24                  Summary                   Buyer 
*day1*
AX1  |  2/1/2019 |Checking inventory  |Invoicing             |The product request started today |  HTN
X5L  |  2/1/2019 |Inventory counting  |Future request planing|No operation update               | null
NO6  |  2/1/2019 |Request in-process  |Closing request       |Operation product request ended   |  KLW
ZS5  |  2/1/2019 |Order placed        |Processing request    |Request started for the product   |  WHM
*day2* 
AX1  |  3/1/2019 |Invoicing the order |Logistic planning     |Product requested still pending   |  HTN
X5L  |  3/1/2019 |New request planing |processing order      |A new product request started     |  LKJ
NO6  |  3/1/2019 |Closing request     |No new request        |No update for new operation       |  null
ZS5  |  3/1/2019 |Request ended       |New order placed      |Product inventory counting        |  WHM
*day3*
AX1  |  4/1/2019 |Logistic planning   |Closing the request   |Product request ended             |  HTN
X5L  |  4/1/2019 |Request processing  |Planning logistic     |The product request under-process |  LKJ
NO6  |  4/1/2019 |No update           |New Request Planing   |No update for new operation       |  null
ZS5  |  4/1/2019 |New order started   |Request invoicing     |Inventory and logistic planing    |  KLW
```

My ultimate goal is to get the percentage of each buyer orders. And that would mean I need to look for the world in 3 columns (Last24, Next 24 and Summary)
So to get that I need to make sure that **if** Product == Product **and** Buyer == Buyer **then** search Last24 **or** Next24 **or** Summary for string 'ended'

The result would look like this table

```
Product   Date         Lsat24               Next24                      Summary                   Buyer 
*day1*
NO6  |  2/1/2019 |Request in-process  |Closing request       |Operation product request ended   |  KLW
*day2* 
ZS5  |  3/1/2019 |Request ended       |New order placed      |Product inventory counting        |  WHM
*day3*
AX1  |  4/1/2019 |Logistic planning   |Closing the request   |Product request ended             |  HTN
```

So the real data table (in excel) has over 200 products. These products will be repeated everyday. The Last24, Next24 and summary for each product is different every day. Also the buyer can change(Not always).

I am using Python3.8.

Edit"

To make my question clear I will use examples.

```
  Product   Date         Lsat24               Next24                  Summary                   Buyer 
*day1*
0  AX1  |  2/1/2019  |Checking inventory  |Invoicing            |The product request started today |  HTN
1  X5L  |  2/1/2019  |Inventory counting |Future request planing|No operation update               | null
2  NO6  |  2/1/2019 |Request in-process  |Closing request       |Operation product request ended   |  KLW
3  ZS5  |  2/1/2019 |Order placed        |Processing request    |Request started for the product   |  WHM
*day2* 
4  AX1  |  3/1/2019 |Invoicing the order |Logistic planning     |Product requested still pending   |  HTN
5  X5L  |  3/1/2019 |New request planing |processing order      |A new product request started     |  LKJ
6  NO6  |  3/1/2019 |Closing request     |No new request        |No update for new operation       |  null
7  ZS5  |  3/1/2019 |Request ended       |New order placed      |Product inventory counting        |  WHM
*day3*
8  AX1  |  4/1/2019 |Logistic planning   |Closing the request   |Product request ended             |  HTN
9  X5L  |  4/1/2019 |Request processing  |Planning logistic     |The product request under-process |  LKJ
10 NO6  |  4/1/2019 |No update           |New Request Planing   |No update for new operation       |  null
11 ZS5  |  4/1/2019 |New order started   |Request invoicing     |Inventory and logistic planing    |  KLW
```

One case

*if** Product == Product ([1] X5L == [5] X5L) then go for  Buyer == Buyer ([1] null != [5] LKJ(since they do not match)  search in row [1] for "ended" in Last24 **or** Next24 **or** Summary, if "ended" is found in at least one of the 3 columns return the row[1] else remove it)

The other case

*if** Product == Product ([0] AX1 == [4] AX1), then go for Buyer == Buyer ([0]HTN == [4]HTN, since they match go for the next row with the same product name. 
Product == Product ([4]AX1 ==[8] AX1), then  Buyer == Buyer ([4]HTN == [8]HTN), since they match and no new row with the same product name, search in row [8] for "ended" in Last24 **or** Next24 **or** Summary).

It is a bit complicated, Iknow.

Comment: do you have any working code for reference

Answer (score 4):

I think you need [`Series.str.endswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.endswith.html) for looking for string in 3 columns with [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for test at least one `True` - one match per row and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
cols = ['Lsat24','Next24','Summary']
df = df[df[cols].apply(lambda x : x.str.endswith('ended')).any(axis=1)]

print (df)
  Product      Date              Lsat24               Next24  \
2     NO6  2/1/2019  Request in-process      Closing request   
7     ZS5  3/1/2019       Request ended     New order placed   
8     AX1  4/1/2019   Logistic planning  Closing the request   

                           Summary Buyer  
2  Operation product request ended   KLW  
7       Product inventory counting   WHM  
8            Product request ended   HTN
```

Comment: Tanks but this only works if the 'ended' in all three column . which is not what I want. I need to match the product name first then look match the buyer name and if true then find the key word "ended" in any of three columns not all of them.

Comment: @Sarah - Not understand, . I need to match the product name first - Do you think  first `NO6`? And what means `then look match the buyer name` ? `NO6` not match `KLW`, can you explain more?

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make myself clear. I will update my question .

Comment: @Sarah - Ok, please updare question for [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Sarah - Not understand `Product == Product ([1] X5L == [5] X5L)`

Comment: that mean I need to compare every row using the product value([1] and [5] is the index) and if two rows has the same product value then compare the buyer value in the two rows, if they both (product and buyer values) match then keep go to next row 'till the buyer value changes. When the buyer value change , search for the string "ended" in any of the 3 columns ( Lsat24, Next24, or Summary). It only need to be found in any of them.